Is there a version of Trolley problem without the actual result being known?
I was making some readings on the Trolley Problem but it caught my attention that most of examples and different versions include, without any intervention, the actual path of the trolley is known to the driver or the bystander, indicating that the trolley is going to crash more people and leave the single person on the tracks alive. I was wondering what would be the moral implications on deciding killing the one person if the regular path of the trolley is not known and there exist a chance of the trolley to hit the single person even without changing the course? Or is there an existing work on such a version of the problem?

Ethics and morals should not be conflated: our ideology doesn't see a distinction just because current morals are purely "pragmatic"...  Anyway, my answer to your question would be that if the bystander is not in control, s/he has no decision to make, ergo there is no problem... no?

I meant as the bystander is in control, s/he can choose whether to hit 1 or 5 people, but is not aware of the actual course of the tracks, meaning that if s/he do not intervene there exists a possibility of the trolley to go towards the single person. Only thing is that s/he doesn't have the probabilities of the trolley randomly choosing either side.

S/he cannot reasonably "choose" anything if all s/he has is a button but s/he can neither assess the situation (where the train is presently going) nor the outcome of pushing that button (how it affects the train path).  In which case I'd propose the best course of action would indeed be "(raise an alarm if there is one, then) do nothing (and pray)".

It is as if s/he can either choose for 100% certainity to kill 1 person, or let the trolley go on as it is and hit 5 or 1 with unknown probabilty (at least to the driver/bystander) but have no responsibility on the matter. I thought as the tracks are a perfect Y shape and it is completely random for trolley to go left or right.

You can probably find a lot of writing if you search "probabilistic" or "uncertain" along with "trolley problem". I think Philippa Foot mentions in her original paper that these sorts of situations are of course uncommon in real life; they are extremely binary and well-defined choices to serve as instructive testcases for philosophy

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive, in philosophy, "ethics" and "morals" are synonyms. In regular speech, some people feel they have different connotations, but even that is questionable.

100% agree with @DavidGudeman here, morals are indeed conflated with ethics, though I could argue a difference in academic speak. In general usage they’re often interchangeable

@CevatA.Bezirgan love to hear more about what your interested in here as an answer. I myself am very keen on probabilistic views on ethics as they seem to bridge a  divide between ethics and applied ethics. In terms of automated cars in relation to the trolley problem, I believe it’s a bad formulation of the reality of the situation, which quite likely is made up of lots of “options” with lots of probabilistic outcomes.

Crash Blossoms.

The trolley problem has become somewhat of a meme in popculture and there are countless of variations and analogues:
https://themindcollection.com/trolley-problem-meme-variations/
just to name a few. There are apparently also a variety of variations by more seriously interested people:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem#/media/File:The_trolley_problem.svg
So it's definitely possible that such a variation exists and it's not hard to make one up:
Imagine you observe an undecided person being tasked with a trolley problem and they constantly switch tracks so you have no idea where they will end up. Or if that 2nd agent is too much, imagine a non-agent, idk someone having tied his dog to the lever while taking a long shit and now the dog erratically moves around switching tracks.
The problem is that this doesn't really add much to the problem.
For what it's worth both of these scenarios take pressure off from the observer. In the first case someone else is already trying to solve the problem, so you could sit back and consider it their task or could negotiate with them and maintain comfort from not being alone, while in the other case you could excuse yourself by a rush of adrenaline from having the urgent necessity to untie the dog or the ability to say that you came late, the ability to see that as "fate" or a cosmic coin toss absolving you from responsibility to act.
While that is kind of the crucial element for the trolley problem. You know that either outcome is bad, you see that clearly, there are no excuses and you're forced to make a decision of action or inaction, how would you act and why.
So it's rather unlikely that this would become a much debated issue of the trolley problem, because it only introduces more aspects that effectively let you ignore the problem.

First I found some links for you if you really wanna dig into some works about it.
https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/trolley-problem/nonconsequentialist-principles-under-conditions-of-uncertainty/FC42333865784D6A6C1DBAAAEA65BB3A
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-decision-uncertainty/
https://www.currentaffairs.org/news/2017/11/the-trolley-problem-will-tell-you-nothing-useful-about-morality
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22353427/
I was wondering what would be the moral implications on deciding killing the one person if the regular path of the trolley is not known and there exist a chance of the trolley to hit the single person even without changing the course?

The Principle of Double Effect
There is this kinda principle, often used in Catholic ethics. It says it's morally permissible to perform an action that has both good and bad consequences, as long as the good effect is intended and the bad effect is not directly intended. In the Uncertain Trolley Problem, if you switch tracks, you might be aiming to save more lives (good effect), but you're also risking harming the person on the other track (bad effect). The question is whether the bad effect is a foreseeable consequence or a direct intention.
The Problem of Proportionality
Even if you accept the Principle of Double Effect, you still need to consider whether the good effect outweighs the bad effect. In the Uncertain Trolley Problem, you'd need to weigh the potential for saving lives on one track against the potential for harming the person on the other track. This is difficult without knowing the probabilities involved.
And if you act without full knowledge, are you still morally responsible for the consequences? Some guys might say that ignorance doesn't excuse us from moral responsibility, especially if we could have taken steps to gain more information. Others argue that we can't be held accountable for outcomes we couldn't have foreseen.
